# C#: Displaying text in richtextbox in reverse order/updwards

Tags: c#, richtextbox, reverse, rtf

I am trying to create a 'log display' using the richtextbox control in C#.NET.

```
public void logLine(string line)
{
     rtxtLoginMessage.AppendText(line + "\r\n");
}
```

Is there a way to display the text in reverse order/upwards? (where the newest log and date will be displayed at the top)

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short Answer**

You want to set the selection to 0 and then set the `SelectedText` property.

```
public void logLine(string line)
{
    rtxtLoginMessage.Select(0, 0);    
    rtxtLoginMessage.SelectedText = line + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

**Long Answer**

How did I work this out?

Using [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/), search for the RichTextBox control and find the `AppendText` method (follow the base types to `TextBoxBase`). Have a look at what it does (below for convenience).

```
public void AppendText(string text)
{
    if (text.Length > 0)
    {
        int num;
        int num2;
        this.GetSelectionStartAndLength(out num, out num2);
        try
        {
            int endPosition = this.GetEndPosition();
            this.SelectInternal(endPosition, endPosition, endPosition);
            this.SelectedText = text;
        }
        finally
        {
            if ((base.Width == 0) || (base.Height == 0))
            {
                this.Select(num, num2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You will see that it finds the end position, sets the internal selection, and then sets the `SelectedText` to the new value. To insert text at the very beginning you simply want to find the **start position** instead of the **end position**.

Now, so you do not have repeat this piece of code for each time you want to prefix text you can create an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

```
public static void PrependText(this TextBoxBase textBox, string text)
{
    if (text.Length > 0)
    {
        var start = textBox.SelectionStart;
        var length = textBox.SelectionLength;

        try
        {
            textBox.Select(0, 0);
            textBox.SelectedText = text;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (textBox.Width == 0 || textBox.Height == 0)
                textBox.Select(start, length);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I'm only using the `Try/Finally` block to match the implementation of `AppendText`. I'm not certain as *why* we would want to restore the initial selection if the `Width` or `Height` is 0 (if you do know why, please leave a comment as I'm interested in finding out).

Also, there is some contention to using "Prepend" as the opposite for "Append" as the direct English definition is confusing (do a Google search - there are several posts on the topic). However, if you look at the [Barron's Dictionary of Computer Terms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764134175) it has become an accepted use.

HTH,

Dennis

Comment: Nice... I may have to use this. Been thinkin of how to have a downward scrolling, top inserting log thingy...

Comment: thanks for the PrependText extension method, I tried hard to find something to have same function with `richtextbox.Text.Insert(0,text)`

Answer (score 3):

```
  public void logLine(string line)
  {     
       rtxtLoginMessage.Select(0, 0);        
       rtxtLoginMessage.SelectedText = line + "\r\n";
  }
```